# Incorrect credit card expiration date Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am creating custom payment gateway for Magento 2 but facing error in credit card form.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other payment gateways on your site? If so, check that your expiration field is not a duplication of a field on another gateway. It may be unable to get the correct value. You may want to disable other gateway modules to test this.

I'm having a similar conflict with SagePay and BitPay payment gateways.